# Sri bhagavad ayya says "There is nothing to be done"

Tags: guru, sadhana, mukti

**"Everything which is achieved, has to be loosed away"** which means Liberation is not a sate which can be attained because we are already liberated, we just have to see it.

Liberation is very simple thing, like the normal taste of tongue, (not sweet, not bitter just no taste at all). It's like I am waiting for something great to happen, but there is nothing to be happened.

This book "Renounce God be Good", Which is telling us the way to achieve a state of Nirvana, Mukti, Liberation, self realization.

This Guru says something interesting that "There is nothing to be done", that is all we need to realize.

He says 2 ways:

1: One directly feels I am Atman and got liberated, but it happens to 1 in a billion.

2: One totally surrenders himself to God, his every action everything is GOD, this happens to 1 in a Million.

One the same page it says but with understanding 100 out of 100 can be liberated. (That understanding is just let the mind work)

By letting our mind work naturally. I do not get it, what is Sadhna here?

What I understand from this book is he is trying to say had actually confused me (Guru's always confuses Layman) by saying there is nothing to be achieved.

It says let the mind work naturally and you will find out active state becomes a dream state.

Can any one please help me What this book is trying to say or if some one know the teachings of this Guru, Kindly explain.

Comment: Who is bhagavad ayya?

Comment: @moonstar2001 Google "Sri bagavath ayya", He is the author of the book and a spiritual guru in Tamil Nadu. Claimed to get enlightened at age 58 and any one can go and meet him in his ashram.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because one cannot validate the statements of anyone and everyone. We may only quote scripture or established guru parampara.

Comment: You need provide a copy of the relevant pages from the book for someone to read and answer your question. For now, I'm voting to close.

Comment: This sounds pure Advaita to me. Read Ashtavakra Samhita, you will understand what Sri Bhagavad Ayya is saying.

Comment: @sv. I will add the relevant pages from the book, today evening

Comment: just a thought that if anyone can meet him then why cant you meet him and ask for clarification :)

Comment: @Friendy Yes you are right, but it is just 2469 kilo meters away...) from my place.

Comment: Quotes from the book will not give authenticity to the author of the book. I can self-publish my own stream of consciousness but that does not bestow standard upon the book. Such standard will be earned after recognized scholars accept it , provide commentary corroborating sentences from the book by referencing scripture. This Q needs to be closed.

Comment: @Rishi Once you add the pages from the book, you can flag the mods to re-open.